# Table format won't show x values

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a table with a header that seems to be ruining my plots.

```
        | Header2 | 
--------+---------+
a       | 1       | 
b       | 5       |
c       | 7       |
```

I want to barplot the x and y values against each other, and I can, but it does not print out the values "a,b,c" on the x-axis

And when I run:

```
barplot(xyz.rf$importance[order(xyz.rf$importance, decreasing = TRUE)], ylim=c(0,40) las=2)
```

It does not print out the x values on the graph

*xyz.rf$importance* looks like this:

```
           MeanDecreaseGini
a            25.803414
b            20.671604
c            14.043655
d            20.307379
e            27.805377
f            11.427971
g            14.104592
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add some data from `xyz.rf` as part of question. It will help others to reply.

Comment: If it is a `table`, the `$` wont work.  You may need `xyz.rf[, 'importance']`

Comment: I have added the table.

Comment: It is not clear about the structure..  Perhaps you need `xyz.rf$importance$MeanDecreaseGini`

Comment: Have a look at dput function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could transpose the object

```
barplot(t(df1), ylim=c(0,40), las=2)
```

[image]

where,

```
df <- xyz.rf$importance
df1 <- df[order(df[, "MeanDecreaseGini"], decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Why does this work exactly, but my method above didn't work?

Comment: @H.Ozdil  According to `barplot` `If ‘height’ is a matrix and ‘beside’
          is ‘FALSE’ then each bar of the plot corresponds to a column
          of ‘height’, with the values in the column giving the heights
          of stacked sub-bars making up the bar.`  If we don't transpose, then there is only a single column and barplot works on `vector` and `matrix`.  I am not sure whether you have a matrix or data.frame.  Assuming that you had a matrix, the 'x' axis label will be 'MeanDecreasingGini'